# RegEx/SED? Replace hierarchical paths in an XML file with a single directory name

Tags: xml, regex, file, sed, itunes

I'm hoping somebody can help me with this - I suspect the answer may be a RegEx or Sed command but I have no idea how to do this.

Context: I wanted to clear out my iTunes music collection and so I created an iTunes playlist and copied the corresponding mp3/aacs that I wanted to keep to a USB drive.  A fragment relating to one song in the playlist XML file is below:

```
<key>Persistent ID</key><string>B123AA625019E726</string>
<key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
<key>Purchased</key><true/>
<key>Location</key><string>file://localhost/Users/bc/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/Adele/21/01%20Rolling%20In%20The%20Deep.m4a</string>
<key>File Folder Count</key><integer>5</integer>
<key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>1</integer>
```

I then installed Mavericks (Mac) after deleting the whole library and had the intention of importing back in what I had exported.  The problem is that the music files copied to a single folder and the playlist references the original hierarchical locations.  I would like to change the 'Location' value for each song in the playlist to be the new single directory so that I can import the playlist back and keep the metadata for each song.  I find/replace will not work as the original locations are 2/3/4 etc levels deep.  I can get to a Mac or Linux prompt if that helps.  Is there somebody who can help me with this?

Thanks (a lot) in advance if you can help!

Ben

Comment: Are you saying all songs are in a single folder now, so anything before the last / in the location needs to be replaced?

Comment: The example in the question is not valid XML: ``<key>Location</key<string>``. Typo or corrupted file?

Comment: Hi Harald, yes that's exactly correct - all of the music files are now in a single folder :(  The original folder locations as shown in the above XML file are 'n' levels deep - (some by artist, album - others by compilation etc).  I wish to replace these 'n' levels with a path to the single folder that I am now left with so that I can import this playlist (including metadata) back in.

Comment: Hi Louis, you are right - it is not valid XML!  This is not a typo but it is how iTunes stores its data!

Comment: you should explain more precisely, what is input and what desired output. Give an example.

Comment: Hi Enduro, in the example above, there are many <key>Location</key><string> nodes for different music files of different artists.  All have the same path up to /iTunes Media/Music/.  Then is the artist name (Adele here) and sometimes an album (21).  Then appears the filename.  I would like to remove all Artist names from these strings and any references to Album.  In the example above, I would like to be left with: <key>Location</key><string>file://localhost/Users/bc/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/01%20Rolling%20In%20The%20Deep.m4a</string> . I hope that is clearer and you can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses sed to replace the string "file://localhost/Users/bc" with "file:///home/bc"

## Example

```
$ sed -e 's/file:\/\/localhost\/Users\/bc/file:\/\/\/home\/bc/g' data.xml
<song>
  <key>Persistent ID</key>
  <string>B123AA625019E726</string>
  <key>Track Type</key>
  <string>File</string>
  <key>Purchased</key>
  <true/>
  <key>Location</key>
  <string>file:///home/bc/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/Adele/21/01%20Rolling%20In%20The%20Deep.m4a</string>
  <key>File Folder Count</key>
  <integer>5</integer>
  <key>Library Folder Count</key>
  <integer>1</integer>
</song>
```

### data.xml

```
<song>
  <key>Persistent ID</key>
  <string>B123AA625019E726</string>
  <key>Track Type</key>
  <string>File</string>
  <key>Purchased</key>
  <true/>
  <key>Location</key>
  <string>file://localhost/Users/bc/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/Adele/21/01%20Rolling%20In%20The%20Deep.m4a</string>
  <key>File Folder Count</key>
  <integer>5</integer>
  <key>Library Folder Count</key>
  <integer>1</integer>
</song>
```

Comment: Hi Mark, each of the strings 'file://localhost/Users/bc' that relate to a music file would have the music file under an arbitrary number of sub-directories.  I wish to replace the arbitrary number of directories with one directory - I guess you would need a RegEx for that - can you confirm - do you know what it would be?!?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your music files are all under sub folders of file://localhost/Users/bc/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/Adele/ and you want to change them to directly under file://localhost/Users/bc/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/Adele/

```
sed '/<key>Location<\/key</s!file://localhost/Users/bc/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music
/Adele/.*/\([^/]\+\)</string>!file://localhost/Users/bc/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music
/Adele/\1</string>!' data.xml
```

`/<Key>Location<\/key<` matches the line you need to change, then substitute, remove all sub folders after Adele, remain the name of file as \1 and append it to path Adele/

My script just output the new content to the console, you can redirect it to a new xml file like

```
sed '/<key>Location<\/key</s!file://localhost/Users/bc/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music
/Adele/.*/\([^/]\+\)</string>!file://localhost/Users/bc/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music
/Adele/\1</string>!' data.xml > data_new.xml
```

Thanks to Francisco to point out my edit error

Comment: Hi QAMichaelPeng!  Your assumption is precisely correct.  I tried your sed command but it doesn't change anything in the file.  Here is another sample of the location node:           <key>Location</key><string>file://localhost/Users/bc/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/Kavinsky/Nightcall%20-%20Single/01%20Nightcall.m4a</string>

Comment: There was this reply from @QAMichaelPeng in an invalid edit:
My script just output the new content to the console, you can redirect it to a new xml file like sed `/Location</key!file://localhost/Users/bc/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/Adele/\1!` data.xml > data_new.xml

Comment: Thanks Francisco and QAMichaelPeng very much.  I tried what you suggested and the file outputted is the same as the input file. Here is another example of the Location node if that helps:    <key>Location</key><string>file://localhost/Users/bc/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/Syd%20Matters/Brotherocean/02%20Hi%20Life.m4a</string>  Incidentally in the example above, I would like all music files to appear under the Music folder (not Music/Adele/) so I assume I just remove Adele.  Thanks again - Happy New Year!